# Cron Job not running in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I created a cron job in my console in Ubuntu 12.04) by using `crontab -e`:

```
10 09 * * * /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/dump.sh
```

But it is not running. When I save it is installed correctly without errors then when I view it using `crontab -l` it shows my crontab, but it not running in time.

My `dump.sh` contains backup database command’s and if I try to run separately that `.sh` file runs correctly.

Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

The contents of the `dump.sh` code is:

```
cd
cd Desktop/bala/personal
mkdir $(date +%Y%m%d)
cd $(date +%Y%m%d)
mysqldump -u root -p*** --all-databases |gzip -9  >database-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz
```

Comment: yes i want to run dump.sh,time doesn't matter i tried to execute at 09.10 am,but it's not running

Comment: What does your Cron log say ?

Comment: @Charm_Quark:i looked at logs there is no log file created for cron,i looked in var/log/ ..

Comment: export the output of the cron job to what the issues is eg : 10 09 * * * /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/dump.sh >> /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/cron.log and also check the permission of the script

Answer (score 1):

This is your cron job and it looks fine:

```
10 09 * * * /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/dump.sh
```

Set to fire off every day at 9:10am. But looking at your script shows the issue:

```
cd
cd Desktop/bala/personal
mkdir $(date +%Y%m%d)
cd $(date +%Y%m%d)
mysqldump -u root -p*** --all-databases |gzip -9 >database-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz
```

When a cron job runs, it does not run as you—the user—so paths to binary files won’t be loaded. So the script has no idea where `mysqldump` is. So you should run [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) to figure out what the full path is like this:

```
which mysqldump
```

And the output should be something like this; using a generic example here:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysqldump
```

Also, you should add a script designation as the first line of the file so the shell knows what environment should run it. Also the `cd` and following `cd Desktop/bala/personal` can be simplified to `cd ~/Desktop/bala/personal`. So the whole new script would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd ~/Desktop/bala/personal
mkdir $(date +%Y%m%d)
cd $(date +%Y%m%d)
/usr/local/bin/mysqldump -u root -p*** --all-databases |gzip -9 >database-$(date +%Y%m%d).sql.gz
```

Try running that on your own—from the command line—to see if it works. And if it does, run it from the cron again.

Comment: Sorry,it was also not running..

Comment: :i tried your method ,it was running in command line,but not in cron..

Answer (score 0):

Set up the cron job as below, so that you catch the errors when executing the script and also your username eg: charm_quark

```
  10 09 * * * charm_quark /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/dump.sh >>  /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/cron.log
```

Also check your permission and environments

Before using a custom script, make sure it is executable and test it with the limited set of environment variables set by cron. To replicate the environment that would be used to run the above cron entry, use:

```
env -i SHELL=/bin/sh PATH=/etc:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin HOME=/home/dru LOGNAME=dru /usr/home/dru/bin/mycustomscript.sh
```

Reference: [Chapter 12. Configuration and Tuning](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html)

**Troubleshooting steps**

1. Empty the dump.sh file and replace it with some echo's

   `#!/usr/bin/env bash 
   echo "this is a test" >> /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/test.log`
2. Check the permission of the .sh file and change it.

   `chmod 777 /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/dump.sh`
3. Please update crontab to

   `* * * * * charm_quark /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/dump.sh >> /home/ram-pc/Desktop/bala/personal/cron.log`

Comment: Sorry it is also not running and cron.log is empty no errors,if i try the cron script it is running successfully

Comment: the same result coming ,cron.log has no data

Comment: no test.log is not created at all

Comment: can you please show the , crontab , and the script, and the permissions of the file.

Comment: yup, 777 is bad, but i'm trying to figure out what the issue is exactly, if there are no outputs in the logs! need to find out if the script is actually being run. may be a more underlying issue.

Comment: Sorry That is also not working,but it creates a empty cron.log file alone

Comment: I changed it to 755 ,but that is also not working